# Leetcode 104 Maximum Depth of Binary Tree. Why is one iterative solution not working while the other one is

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

So I'm currently solving 104 problem on leetcode and I came across that my way of implementing the iterative solution using BFS doesn't work with the following loop

```java
while(!queue.isEmpty()){                       

            for(int i = 0; i< queue.size(); i++){
                TreeNode node = queue.remove();                
                
                if(node.left != null){
                    queue.add(node.left);
                }
                if(node.right != null){
                    queue.add(node.right); 
                }
            }  
            currentLevel++;
            
 }
```

However looking it up online doing the loop this way DOES work

```java
while(!queue.isEmpty()){                       
            int size = queue.size();
            while(size -- > 0){
                TreeNode node = queue.remove();                
                
                if(node.left != null){
                    queue.add(node.left);
                }
                if(node.right != null){
                    queue.add(node.right); 
                }
            }  
            currentLevel++;
            
        }
```

I'm just trying to understand why for a specific case mine doesn't work but the other one does.

Case:
Tree: [0,2,4,1,null,3,-1,5,1,null,6,null,8]

Visualization:

```
      0
     / \
    2   4
   /   / \
  1   3  -1
 / \   \   \
5   1   6   8
```

First snippet result = 5

Second snippet result = 4

Expected result = 4

Comment: Because `queue.size()` changes when you call `queue.add()`. To fix your code, change the loop to `for (i = queue.size(); i > 0; i--)`. That way, you only call `queue.size()` once, before any calls to `queue.add()`

Comment: To figure these things out by yourself, you need to learn how to use print statements to see what's going on in your code. For example, print `i` and `queue.size()` at the top of the `for` loop in your code. Then print `size` and `queue.size()` at the top of the `while` loop in the working code. And in both cases, print a blank line after the `currentLevel++` line. That way, you can see what happened in the inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider *iteration condition changes* when you iterate over a collection.

Your iteration condition is **the initial size of queue being greater than zero**.

```
...
int size = queue.size();
    while(size -- > 0){
...
```

The second implementation puts the initial queue size to a variable and ensures the fixed number of loop iterations by not changing it inside the loop.

The first implementation **calculates queue size at the beginning of each loop iteration**, but the current queue size changes as you add and remove values to the queue inside for loop, which in turn becomes an invalid solution.

```
...
for(int i = 0; i< queue.size(); i++){
...
```